# Creating dynamically grid in Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

Kendo UI for Angular has a grid that can be defined as follows:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="ID" width="40">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Name" width="250">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Category">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Price" width="80">
            </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

But what I ned to do is to dynamically build the columns. Something like:

```
var grid = new KendoGrid();
var column = new KendoGridColumn();
grid.add(column);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot create a grid like this.

Alternatively you could generate the columns via `ngFor`.

```
public columns = [
    { field:'ProductID', title:'ID', width:250 },
    { field:'Category.CategoryName', title:'Category' }
];
```

**html**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [height]="410">
    <kendo-grid-column
        *ngFor="let column of columns"
        [field]="column.field"
        [title]="column.title"
        [width]="column.width">
    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```